Ошибка при запуске конфигурации 1С:Предприятие
При попытке открыть конфигурацию, что через конфигуратор, что через предприятие появляется ошибка: "Разрешение обновления не связано с запросом на обновление" в интернете не смог отрыть информацию, может здесь помогут.
Остальные конфигурации спокойно открываются и работают. 

Какая конфигурация и версия, какая версия платформы, база клиент-серверная? Было ли в конфигурации настроено в режиме предприятия автоматическое обновление?

Версия 1С - 8.3. Автоматического обновления нет, клиент тонкий, не клиент - серверная. Делал лабораторки дома, пришел на пару, и вот такая ошибка вылезла, в настройках в принципе ничего никогда не трогал, как информационную базу создал так и пользовался

Запускал так же на своём компьютере или приходил с выгрузкой базы?

На личном компьютере какая платформа стояла? Учебная, для разработчика, взломанная?

Извиняюсь, что сразу не ответил, как я понимаю для разработчиков, да на своём компе, в универе 1с нет на компах.

Как вообще всё было, у меня не было в предпоследней лабе там кое-что не доделано было, я попросил приятеля (так как у нас одинаковые) скинуть его конфигурацию, он мне кинул папку со всеми файлами, ну т.е. просто при создании конфигурации нужно было выбрать создать существующую базу и выбрать эту папку, в настройках при добавлении ничего не тыкал, всё как у него выбирал и она работала. В коде только там текст имени поменял, но это в ряд ли повлияло. Тк это просто строка в " ", ну и начал уже дальше последнее задание в этой же конфигурации делать, там бизнес процесс добавить нужно было.

Всё сделал, протестировал несколько раз, всё работает, выключил комп, пришёл в универ, включил комп и поймал вот эту ошибку.

Сейчас уже пришлось сделать по новой то же самое, ну, добавил в ещё одну новую конфигурацию его, всё опять переделал и опять добавил бизнес процесс, только сейчас всё работает, а та конфигурация всё так же не запускается и хз что ей не так

Всё равно много не понятного. Если он вам присылал конфигурацию, то это один файл *.cf в общем случае (либо много файлов, если была выгружена командой "Выгрузить конфигурацию в файлы").
Если он вам просто папку скинул, где была база, то возможно какие-то разногласия возникли в платформе. Тут надо всё анализировать, сверять. Какая у него платформа была, какая лицензия.
